# How can I set a path prefix for scdf UI

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

How can i set a path prefix for scdf UI. I already set the tomcat property (like server.contextPath=/api/) which works for the rest API but the UI is still giving errors.

Info: i have it running in Kubernetes using ingress.

Answer (score 0):

We do not support GUI redirects with a overridden `contextPath`. The Dashboard is a SPA and this type of interaction requires special handling from the client-side.

Feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-ui/issues) and consider also contributing to the project.